# SSL certificate and React Native Axios

Tags: react-native, api, ssl, axios

I'm using Axios in react native application to make calls to HTTPS API, but I have a problem with the SSL  verification. for that, I want to ask if there is any way to (ignore) the SSL verification using Axios.

note that it's a GoDaddy certificate and I cannot change it.

Answer (score -4):

Add this configuration to axios and set rejectUnauthorized to false:

```
// At instance level
const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
});
instance.get('https://something.com/foo');

// At request level
const agent = new https.Agent({  
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});
axios.get('https://something.com/foo', { httpsAgent: agent });
```

Comment: but what about https module? react says not found, can i import it in react native?

Comment: check this : https://github.com/infinitered/apisauce/issues/136

Comment: You're welcome ,kindly tell the results so it help others too.

Comment: until now I didn't solve the problem.. when I did, I will post the solution